# Keras : How should I prepare input data for RNN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm having trouble with preparing input data for RNN on Keras.

Currently, my training data dimension is: `(6752, 600, 13)`

- 6752: number of training data
- 600: number of time steps
- 13: size of feature vectors (the vector is in float)

`X_train` and `Y_train` are both in this dimension.

I want to prepare this data to be fed into `SimpleRNN` on Keras.
Suppose that we're going through time steps, from step #0 to step #599.
Let's say I want to use `input_length = 5`, which means that I want to use recent 5 inputs. (e.g. step #10, #11,#12,#13,#14 @ step #14).

How should I reshape `X_train`?

should it be `(6752, 5, 600, 13)` or should it be `(6752, 600, 5, 13)`?

And what shape should `Y_train` be in?

Should it be `(6752, 600, 13)` or `(6752, 1, 600, 13)` or `(6752, 600, 1, 13)`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you only want to predict the output using the most recent 5 inputs, there is no need to ever provide the full 600 time steps of any training sample. My suggestion would be to pass the training data in the following manner:

```
             t=0  t=1  t=2  t=3  t=4  t=5  ...  t=598  t=599
sample0      |---------------------|
sample0           |---------------------|
sample0                |-----------------
...
sample0                                         ----|
sample0                                         ----------|
sample1      |---------------------|
sample1           |---------------------|
sample1                |-----------------
....
....
sample6751                                      ----|
sample6751                                      ----------|
```

The total number of training sequences will sum up to

```
(600 - 4) * 6752 = 4024192    # (nb_timesteps - discarded_tailing_timesteps) * nb_samples
```

Each training sequence consists of 5 time steps. At each time step of every sequence you pass all 13 elements of the feature vector. Subsequently, the shape of the training data will be (4024192, 5, 13).

This loop can reshape your data:

```py
input = np.random.rand(6752,600,13)
nb_timesteps = 5

flag = 0

for sample in range(input.shape[0]):
    tmp = np.array([input[sample,i:i+nb_timesteps,:] for i in range(input.shape[1] - nb_timesteps + 1)])

    if flag==0:
        new_input = tmp
        flag = 1

    else:
        new_input = np.concatenate((new_input,tmp))
```

Answer (score 7):

this is a fast procedure to create 3D data for LSTN/RNN without loops and involving this simple function

```
def create_windows(data, window_shape, step = 1, start_id = None, end_id = None):
    
    data = np.asarray(data)
    data = data.reshape(-1,1) if np.prod(data.shape) == max(data.shape) else data
        
    start_id = 0 if start_id is None else start_id
    end_id = data.shape[0] if end_id is None else end_id
    
    data = data[int(start_id):int(end_id),:]
    window_shape = (int(window_shape), data.shape[-1])
    step = (int(step),) * data.ndim
    slices = tuple(slice(None, None, st) for st in step)
    indexing_strides = data[slices].strides
    win_indices_shape = ((np.array(data.shape) - window_shape) // step) + 1
    
    new_shape = tuple(list(win_indices_shape) + list(window_shape))
    strides = tuple(list(indexing_strides) + list(data.strides))
    
    window_data = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(data, shape=new_shape, strides=strides)
    
    return np.squeeze(window_data, 1)
```

starting from this sample data:

```
n_sample = 2000
n_feat_inp = 6
n_feat_out = 1

X = np.asarray([np.arange(n_sample)]*n_feat_inp).T # (n_sample, n_feat_inp)
y = np.asarray([np.arange(n_sample)]*n_feat_out).T # (n_sample, n_feat_out)
```

if we want **ONE step** ahead forecast

```
look_back = 5
look_ahead = 1

X_seq = create_windows(X, window_shape = look_back, end_id = -look_ahead)
# X_seq.shape --> (n_sample - look_back, look_back, n_feat_inp)
y_seq = create_windows(y, window_shape = look_ahead, start_id = look_back)
# y_seq.shape --> (n_sample - look_back, look_ahead, n_feat_out)
```

example of generated data:

```
X_seq[0]: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
           [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
           [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]

y_seq[0]: [[5]]
```

if we want **MULTI step** ahead forecast

```
look_back = 5
look_ahead = 3

X_seq = create_windows(X, window_shape = look_back, end_id = -look_ahead)
# X_seq.shape --> (n_sample - look_back - look_ahead + 1, look_back, n_feat_inp)
y_seq = create_windows(y, window_shape = look_ahead, start_id = look_back)
# y_seq.shape --> (n_sample - look_back - look_ahead + 1, look_ahead, n_feat_out)
```

example of generated data:

```
X_seq[0]: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
           [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
           [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
           [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]

y_seq[0]: [[5],
           [6],
           [7]]
```