# RNN LSTM estimation of sinewave frequency and phase

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

To further my understanding of RNN and LSTM I am trying to implement a simple LSTM to estimate the frequency and phase of a sinewave. This is proving to be surprisingly difficult to converge. The MSE is quite high (in the thousands)
The only thing that seems to work a little bit is if I generate sinewaves all having the same phase (starting at the same time) AND the training samples are passed as a vector and not as samples one-at-a-time as in a RNN. Meanwhile, here is the code that does not converge. In this code I have removed the different phase for every frequency
Any thoughts on what is going wrong here

I have looked at this [Keras : How should I prepare input data for RNN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992855/keras-how-should-i-prepare-input-data-for-rnn) and tried to modify my input for this as well, but no luck.

```
from keras.models import Sequential  
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dropout ,Dense 
from keras.layers.recurrent import GRU, LSTM
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

np.random.seed(0)  # For reproducability
TrainingNums = 12000 #Number of Trials
numSampleInEach = 200 #Length of each sinewave
numPhaseExamples = 1 #for each freq, so many different phases

X = np.zeros((TrainingNums,numSampleInEach))
Y = np.zeros((TrainingNums,2))

#create sinewaves here
for iii in range(0, TrainingNums//numPhaseExamples):
    freq = np.round(np.random.randn()*100)
    for kkk in range(0,numPhaseExamples):
    #set timeOffset below to 0, if you want the same phase every run
        timeOffset = 0# 0 for now else np.random.randint(0,90)
        X[iii*numPhaseExamples+kkk,:] = np.sin(2*3.142*freq*np.linspace(0+timeOffset,numSampleInEach-1+timeOffset,numSampleInEach)/10000)
        Y[iii*numPhaseExamples+kkk,0] = freq
        Y[iii*numPhaseExamples+kkk,1] = timeOffset

X = np.reshape(X,(TrainingNums, numSampleInEach,1))
#This below works when there is no phase variation
#X = np.reshape(X,(TrainingNums, numSampleInEach,1))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)

#Now create the RNN
model = Sequential()  
#batch_input_shape = [batch_size,timeStep,dataDimension]
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=   (numSampleInEach,1),return_sequences=True))

#For things to work for freq estimation only the following change helps
#model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(1,numSampleInEach),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation("relu")) 

#second layer of RNN
model.add(LSTM(128,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation("relu")) 

model.add(Dense(2,activation="linear"))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="Nadam") 
print model.summary()

print "Model compiled."
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16, nb_epoch=150, 
      validation_split=0.1)
result = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print 'mse: ', result
```

So questions are:

1. Is it right to expect an RNN to estimate frequency and phase?
2. I have tried a couple of architectures (multi layer LSTM, single layer with more nodes etc). I have tried different architectures as well.

Comment: Made some progress, recording here for others. Primarily there should not be an activation after an LSTM. The activation between the LSTM layers is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the activation after the LSTM is the right answer