# Convolutional neural network Conv1d input shape

Tags: input, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a CNN to classify data. My Data is X[N_data, N_features]
I want to create a neural net capable of classifying it. My problem is concerning the input shape of a Conv1D for the keras back end.

I want to repeat a filter over.. let say 10 features and then keep the same weights for the next ten features. 
For each data my convolutional layer would create N_features/10 New neurones.
How can i do so? What should I put in input_shape?

```
def cnn_model():
model = Sequential()                                               
model.add(Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=10 ,strides=10,     
                  input_shape=(1, 1,N_features),kernel_initializer= 'uniform',      
                  activation= 'relu')) 
model.flatten()
model.add(Dense(N_features/10, init= 'uniform' , activation= 'relu' ))
```

Any advice?
thank you!

Comment: here the fastest and correct way to create data for LSTM/RNN/Conv1D: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62570576/10375049

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Marcin's answer might work, but might suggestion given the documentation here:

> When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide an
>   input_shape argument (tuple of integers or None, e.g. (10, 128) for
>   sequences of 10 vectors of 128-dimensional vectors, or (None, 128) for
>   variable-length sequences of 128-dimensional vectors.

would be:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=10 ,strides=10,     
                  input_shape=(None, N_features),kernel_initializer= 'uniform',      
                  activation= 'relu'))
```

Note that since input data (N_Data, N_features), we set the number of examples as unspecified (None). The `strides` argument controls the size of of the timesteps in this case.

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
def cnn_model():
    model = Sequential()                                               
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=10 ,strides=10,     
              input_shape=(N_features, 1),kernel_initializer= 'uniform',      
              activation= 'relu')) 
model.flatten()
model.add(Dense(N_features/10, init= 'uniform' , activation= 'relu' ))
....
```

And reshape your `x` to shape `(nb_of_examples, nb_of_features, 1)`.

**EDIT:**

`Conv1D` was designed for a sequence analysis - to have convolutional filters which would be the same no matter in which part of sequence we are. The second dimension is so called *features* dimension where you could have a vector of multiple *features* at each of timesteps. One may think about *sequence* dimension the same as *spatial* dimensions and *feature* dimension the same as *channel dimension* or *color dimension* in `Conv2D`. As @putonspectacles mentioned in his comment - you may set *sequence* dimension to `None` in order to make your network *input length invariant*.

Comment: why `input_shape = (1, N_features, 1)`  instead of `input_shape = (, N_features)` ?

Comment: still, why does the input_shape have a third dimension? I just curious/trying to understand.

Comment: `Conv1d` has an input shape of `(timesteps, features)`?

Comment: Ok perfect it worked for me! Thanks
 (but not @putonspectacles method yet )

Comment: So if you could upvote or accept my answer I would cherrish that :)

Comment: What backend this example uses? Maybe input shape should be `(batch_size,sequence_length,n_features)` ? So for example if we use tensorfow backend and want to be able to use sequence of any length, using `Input` layer it would be `inputs = Input((None, N_FEATURES))`

Comment: If i reshape my tabular, `(rows, cols)`, data into `(rows, cols, 1)`, i can see how i could feed it to a Convnet. But according to Keras, we should have `3+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)`, meaning that `input_dim = 1`. I think calling that third dimension as `input_dim` is really confusing and i don't get it at all.

Answer (score 9):

To input a usual feature table data of shape `(nrows, ncols)` to `Conv1d` of `Keras`, following 2 steps are needed:

```
xtrain.reshape(nrows, ncols, 1)
# For conv1d statement: 
input_shape = (ncols, 1)
```

For example, taking first 4 features of `iris` dataset:

To see usual format and its shape:

```
iris_array = np.array(irisdf.iloc[:,:4].values)
print(iris_array[:5])
print(iris_array.shape)
```

The output shows usual format and its shape:

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.6 1.4 0.2]]

(150, 4)
```

Following code alters the format:

```
nrows, ncols = iris_array.shape
iris_array = iris_array.reshape(nrows, ncols, 1)
print(iris_array[:5])
print(iris_array.shape)
```

Output of above code data format and its shape:

```
[[[5.1]
  [3.5]
  [1.4]
  [0.2]]

 [[4.9]
  [3. ]
  [1.4]
  [0.2]]

 [[4.7]
  [3.2]
  [1.3]
  [0.2]]

 [[4.6]
  [3.1]
  [1.5]
  [0.2]]

 [[5. ]
  [3.6]
  [1.4]
  [0.2]]]

(150, 4, 1)
```

This works well for `Conv1d` of `Keras`. For `input_shape` `(4,1)` is needed.