# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_13: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying for multi-class classification and here are the details of my training input and output:

> train_input.shape= (1, 95000, 360) (95000 length input array with each
>   element being an array of 360 length)
>
> train_output.shape = (1, 95000, 22) (22 Classes are there)

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(22, input_shape=(1, 95000,360)))
model.add(Dense(22, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(train_input, train_output, epochs=2, batch_size=500)
```

The error is:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_13: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
>   in line:
>   model.add(LSTM(22, input_shape=(1, 95000,360)))

Please help me out, I am not able to solve it through other answers.

Comment: here the fastest and correct way to create data for LSTM/RNN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62570576/10375049

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I solved the problem by making

> input size: (95000,360,1) and
>   output size: (95000,22)

and changed the **input shape to (360,1)** in the code where model is defined:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(22, input_shape=(360,1)))
model.add(Dense(22, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(ml2_train_input, ml2_train_output_enc, epochs=2, batch_size=500)
```

Answer (score 14):

input_shape is supposed to be (timesteps, n_features). Remove the first dimension.

```
input_shape = (95000,360)
```

Same for the output.

Comment: No, that was also giving some errors like, expected was: None,95000,360 but found 1,95000,360

Comment: That's a problem with your input data shape. The first dimension is supposed to be each sample. Your input should be (n_samples, timesteps, n_features). Looking at your other comment, 95000 is your n_samples not your timesteps. If you only have one feature with 360 timesteps, then the one you proposed is the right format.

Comment: Ok so, my input is having 360-360 blocks(which I want to be treated as features), so what should be the shape of input and what should be written inside here->{model.add(LSTM(22, input_shape=(?)))}

Comment: I need to know what your input is. Is it a time series? How many different variables are you observing? I'll give you an example: if I'm observing the amount of rain and the temperature each hour for 24h in order to predict the weather (1 = good, 0 = bad), and I do that for 365 days, I will have 365 samples, each of which will have 24 timesteps, and 2 variables (one for rain, one for temperature), so my input is going to have the shape (365, 24, 2), and input_shape = (24, 2).

Comment: My input is a *big* array of arrays, each array in the *big* array is having a total of 360 signal values, this 360 chunk is classified as "L" arrhythmia or "R" arrhythmia etc or normal. and there are 95000 such arrays, the *big* array contains all these 95000 samples (initial shape: 95000,360) and output after one hot encoding has the shape:(95000,22) as there are 21 types of arrhythmia and 1 for normal

Comment: So you only have one variable, right? I.e. your signal is a single series of 360 samples of the same thing. In that case what you are doing is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @MicheleTonutti. It's still not working when I try to fit the model although my train shape is (804, 291) and also target (804, 291) as I am building autoencoder.

Answer (score 14):

Well, I think the main problem out there is with the `return_sequences` parameter in the network.This hyper parameter should be set to `False` for the *last layer* and `true` for the other *previous layers*.

Comment: adding to this answer: usually if the error is in the first layer - then the problem might be with `input_shape`. if the problem is in the other layers, then the problem would maybe be in that you need to set `return_sequences -True`

Answer (score 8):

In Artifical Neural Networks (ANN), input is of shape (N,D), where N is the number of samples and D is the number of features.

IN RNN, GRU and LSTM, input is of shape (N,T,D), where N is the number of samples, T is length of time sequence and D is the number of features.

So, while adding layers

Input(shape = (D,)) for ANN and
Input(shape = (T,D)) for RNN, GRU and LSTMs