# How to train Keras LSTM with multiple multivariate time-series data?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a mechanical problem as kind of a time series with raw data as follows

```
        time            dtime   cur         dcur      type  proc    start           end
122088  1554207711521   3140    0.766106    0.130276    0   87556   1554203520000   1554207720000
122089  1554207714411   1800    0.894529    0.089670    0   87556   1554203520000   1554207720000
```

For every `proc`, there is a time series with time-instances not exactly in proper intervals. I have data from a set of different `proc`s, each coming from the same type of mechanical problem. The target is to predict the estimated time left in the process from a new random instance of a random process.

So my label is `eta = end - time`.

I have tried clustering the raw data and use NN regression; and dense NN regression from raw data. But the results are not good enough.

I am thinking of using an LSTM RNN for the time prediction. But I am not sure how exactly should I prepare my data to train the LSTM model. I am guessing I have to create a time-series from each `proc`. But then I have multiple time-series and I do not know how to handle that.

Length of data samples: 122000

Number of uniques `proc`s: 68 (samples per `proc` are not equal)

Suggestions are welcome. Thanks .