# How to input a classification time series data into LSTM

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I want to feed my data into a LSTM network, but can't find any similar question or tutorial. My dataset is something like:

```
person 1:
    t1 f1 f2 f3
    t2 f1 f2 f3
     ...
    tn f1 f2 f3
.
.
.

person K:
    t1 f1 f2 f3
    t2 f1 f2 f3
     ...
    tn f1 f2 f3
```

So i have `k` person and for each person i have a matrix like input. The first column of each row is incremental time stamp (like a time-line, so `t1` < `t2`) and other columns are features of person in that time.

In mathematical aspect: i have a `(number of example,number of time stamp, number of feature)` matrix like (52,20,4) which 52 is number of persons, 20 is number of time stamps for a person and 4 is number of features( 1 column is time stamp and 3 are features)

Each person has a class name. I want to classify this persons into two class using LSTM neural network. My question is how to input this type of data into LSTM in a high level library such as Keras?

**Edit:**
My first attempt is to use this as `input_shape`  in keras, but i get 50% accuracy in binary classification! Is the problem in my dataset or `input_shape` is wrong?!

```
LSTM(5,input_shape=(20,4))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62570576/10375049

Answer (score 2):

You need to represent each person's data with a `feature vector` and pass this vector into the classifier (e.g. [MLP classifier](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#multilayer-perceptron-mlp-for-multi-class-softmax-classification)). I guess your question might be how to get the `feature vector` out of raw data? There are many ways to get feature out of time-series data. In your case, **LSTM** would be an option.

**LSTM** needs a 3D vector for its input with the shape of`[batch_size x time x feature]`. As you mentioned in the question, you can feed data into the model with:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(20, 4))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
```

1) I guess `t` and `f` values vary widely and are not [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling). As a result, the prediction of LSTM is not impressive.

2) Your dataset is relatively small. To find out the issue, overfit the model on a small subset of training data. If you get the accuracy of 100% on training data then it means your LSTM learned to represent feature vectors very well. Otherwise, it implies you do not design a good model or feed data properly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the keras documentation for LSTMs, you're supposed to provide a 3D input shape where the first dimension is the batch size (usually None).  So try input_shape = (None, 20, 4).  This seems to be a common thing with Keras.