# Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 30)

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, lstm, convolution

I have been working on a project for estimating the traffic flow using time series data combine with weather data. I am using a window of 30 values for my time series and I am using 20 weather related features. I have used the functional API to implement this, but I keep getting the same error and I do not know how it can be solved. I have looked at other similar threads such as this one [Input 0 of layer conv1d_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 200]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430717/input-0-of-layer-conv1d-1-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expected-ndim-3-found), but it has not helped.

This is my model,

```
series_input = Input(shape = (series_input_train.shape[1], ), name = 'series_input')
x = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding="causal", activation="relu")(series_input)
x = LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)(x)
x = LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)(x)
x = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(x)
series_output = Lambda(lambda w: w * 200)(x)

weather_input = Input(shape = (weather_input_train.shape[1], ), name = 'weather_input')
x = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(weather_input)
x = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(x)
weather_output = Dense(1, activation = 'relu')(x)

concatenate = concatenate([series_output, weather_output], axis=1, name = 'concatenate')

output = Dense(1, name = 'output')(concatenate)

model = Model([series_input, weather_input], output)
```

The shapes of `series_input_train` and `weather_input_train` are (34970, 30) and (34970, 20) respetively.

The error I keep getting is this one,

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 30)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Honestly, I have always had trouble figuring out how the shape of the inputs work in TensorFlow. If you could point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated but what I need right now is a fix for my model.

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Answer (score 4):

As Tao-Lung says, the first connection for a convolutional layer expects a 3-position form.
1D convolution on sequences expects a 3D input. In other words, for each element of the batch, for each time step, a single vector.
If you want the step to be unitary you solve your problem as follows:

---

series_input = Input(shape = (series_input_train.shape[1],1,)

and

---

x = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding="causal", activation="relu",input_shape=[None,series_input])

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

3+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)
https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/

#### Solution

You don't specify "steps" parameters.
If "steps" is 1, Use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
series_input_train = np.expand_dims(series_input_train, axis=1)
weather_input_train = np.expand_dims(weather_input_train, axis=1)
```

Comment: What will I pass to the Shape parameters of my Input layers then? I get this error now, Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 30) with this layer,  series_input = Input(shape = (series_input_train.shape[1], ), name = 'series_input')

Comment: In the above-mentioned website, 
the inputs are 128-length vectors with 10 timesteps, and the batch size  is 4.
input_shape = (4, 10, 128)

Comment: My inputs are not vectors, they are simply a sequence of 30 values.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had this problem.
Check this link that is mentioned: https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/

the input shape of the Conv1D layer should be A **3D tensor** with shape: (batch_shape, steps, channels) if it's channels_last and (channels, steps, batch_shape) if it's channels_first.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35578563)