# LSTM Keras input shape confusion

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to build a predictive model on stock prices. From what I've read, LSTM is a good layer to use. I can't fully understand what my `input_shape` needs to be for my model though.

Here is the `tail` of my `DataFrame`

[image: print(x_test.shape)]

I then split the data into train / test

```
labels = df['close'].values
x_train_df = df.drop(columns=['close'])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_train_df.values, labels, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x_train = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = min_max_scaler.transform(x_test)

print('y_train', y_train.shape)
print('y_test', y_test.shape)
print('x_train', x_train.shape)
print('x_test', x_test.shape)
print(x_train)
```

This yields:

[image]

Here's where I am getting confused. Running the simple example, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_15 is incompatible with the layer:
>   expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 1, 4026, 5]

I've tried various combinations of messing with the `input_shape` and have came to the conclusion, I have no idea how to determine the input shape.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(1, x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1])))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

Given my dataframe, what should be my `input_shape`? I understand that the input shape is `batch size`, `timesteps`, `data dim`. Just not clear how to map those words to my actual data as what I've thought the values were, are actually not.

I was thinking:

- **Batch Size**: Number of records I'm passing in (4026)
- **Time Steps**: 1 (I'm not sure if this is supposed to be the same value as batch size?)
- **Data Dimension**: 1 since my data is 1 dimensional (I think?)

Comment: here the fastest way to create data for LSTM/RNN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62570576/10375049

Answer (score 11):

First of all, I don't think that you need an LSTM at all. Based on the `df.tail()`, it appears to me that there is no temporal dependence between the rows of the pandas data-frame (the samples of your dataset). Anyways, I will come back to that later, firstly your question:

1. **Batch size:** The number of elements in the batch. In total, the dataset contains 4026 elements. On the other hand, the batch size is the number of elements that are processed in a single batch. Let us assume that it is 2. In that case you will have `2013` of these batches.
2. **Time steps:** Equal to the number of samples which have a temporal dependence between them. Assuming that in your dataset each 3 instances constitute data sequence, then the time steps will be `3`. Therefore, it follows that each sample in the dataset now consists of `3` measurements, so the total number of elements is `1342` (at the start was `4026`).
3. **Data dimension:** The number of features for each element in the batch, for each time step - in your case `5`, assuming that `buy` is the label and `date` is the temporal dependence column.

As a result, the shape of a single batch of data should be `(2, 3, 6)`, while the shape of the whole dataset would be `(1342, 3, 6)`. Please note that these shapes are valid if we consider that you use LSTM and that there is temporal dependence between the each of the time steps. Here is an example code snippet to verify some stuff:

```
# Random training data
x_train = np.random.rand(1342, 3, 6)
# Random training labels
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 2, 1342)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(3, 6)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```

Now, back to my previous point. Looking at `df.tail()`, it seems to me that there is no temporal dependence whatsoever between the samples in the dataset. With that said, I would firstly convert the `date` column to something meaningful (one-hot encoding of the month in the year, one-hot encoding of the 4 seasons depending on the month, etc). Then, instead of constructing an RNN, I will proceed with a feed-forward neural network with a binary classification output layer.

As for the model, once you take care of all data related stuff, something as simple as this should work for you:

```
# Random training data
x_train = np.random.rand(4026, 5)
# Random training labels
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 2, 4026)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=32)
```

Hope that it helps!

Comment: Thanks, @gorjan. Need to process this a little more, but this certainly helps clear up the input_shape params better.

Comment: Sure, I am doing my best to summarize everything in the most concise way. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Also updated the answer with code samples. Hope that it is more clear now.

Comment: @gorjan could you elaborate on why there is no temporal dependence between the rows? I'm wondering if the predictive model could infer some temporal relationships that we cannot immediately see? Also you have said the shape would be `(1342, 3, 6)` - should it not be `(2013, 3, 6)` or `(671, 3, 6)`?