# Keras: val_loss & val_accuracy are not changing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build an LSTM model to predict whether a stock is going up or down the next day. As you can see, a simple classification task that got me stuck for a couple of days now. I am selecting 3 features only to feed into my network, below I am showing my pre-processing:

```
# pre-processing, last column has values of either 1 or zero
len(df.columns) # 32 columns
index_ = len(df.columns) - 1
x = df.iloc[:,:index_]
y = df.iloc[:,index_:].values.astype(int)
```

Removing any nan values:

```
def clean_dataset(df):
    assert isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame), "df needs to be a pd.DataFrame"
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    indices_to_keep = ~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf, 'NaN', 'nan']).any(1)
    return df[indices_to_keep].astype(np.float64)

df = clean_dataset(df)
```

Then I am taking the 3 selected features and showing the shape for `X` and `Y`

```
selected_features = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3']
x = x[selected_features].values.astype(float)
# s.shape (44930, 3)
# y.shape (44930, 1)
```

Then I am splitting my dataset into 80/20

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=98 )
```

Here I am reshaping my data

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1) 
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1) 
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Here is the new shape of each one:

```
x_train.shape = (35944, 3, 1)
x_test.shape = (8986, 3, 1)
y_train.shape = (35944, 1)
y_test.shape = (8986, 1)
```

First sample of the `x_train` set Before reshaping

```
x_train[0] => array([8.05977145e-01, 4.92200000e+01, 1.23157152e+08])
```

First sample of the `x_train` set After reshaping

```
x_train[0] => array([[8.05977145e-01],
                     [4.92200000e+01],
                     [1.23157152e+08]
                      ])
```

Making sure no nan values in my training set both `x_train, and y_train`:

```
for main_index, xx in enumerate(x_train):
  for i, y in enumerate(xx):
    if type(x_train[main_index][i][0]) !=  np.float64:
      print("Something wrong here:" ,main_index, i)
else:
  print("done") # one done, got nothing wrong
```

Finally I am training here LSTM

```
def build_nn():
    model = Sequential()    
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape = (x_train.shape[1], 1), name="one"))) #. input_shape = (None, *x_train.shape) , 
    model.add(Dropout(0.20))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=False, name="three")))
    model.add(Dropout(0.10))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.10))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    opt = Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, decay=0.01)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

filepath = "bilstmv1.h5"
chkp = ModelCheckpoint(monitor = 'val_accuracy', mode = 'auto', filepath=filepath, verbose = 1, save_best_only=True)


model = build_nn()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[chkp])
```

Here is CNN:

```
model.add(Conv1D(256, 3, input_shape = (x_train.shape[1], 1), activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
# opt = Adam(lr=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, decay=0.01)
# opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adamax', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

All seems good until I start training, **both val_loss and val_accuracy are NOT changing when training**

```
Epoch 1/15
1011/1011 [==============================] - 18s 10ms/step - loss: 0.6803 - accuracy: 0.5849 - val_loss: 0.6800 - val_accuracy: 0.5803

Epoch 00001: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.58025, saving model to bilstmv1.h5
Epoch 2/15
1011/1011 [==============================] - 9s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6782 - accuracy: 0.5877 - val_loss: 0.6799 - val_accuracy: 0.5803

Epoch 00002: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58025
Epoch 3/15
1011/1011 [==============================] - 9s 8ms/step - loss: 0.6793 - accuracy: 0.5844 - val_loss: 0.6799 - val_accuracy: 0.5803

Epoch 00003: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58025
Epoch 4/15
1011/1011 [==============================] - 9s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6784 - accuracy: 0.5861 - val_loss: 0.6799 - val_accuracy: 0.5803

Epoch 00004: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58025
Epoch 5/15
1011/1011 [==============================] - 9s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6796 - accuracy: 0.5841 - val_loss: 0.6799 - val_accuracy: 0.5803

Epoch 00005: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58025
Epoch 6/15
1011/1011 [==============================] - 8s 8ms/step - loss: 0.6792 - accuracy: 0.5842 - val_loss: 0.6798 - val_accuracy: 0.5803

Epoch 00006: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58025
Epoch 7/15
1011/1011 [==============================] - 8s 8ms/step - loss: 0.6779 - accuracy: 0.5883 - val_loss: 0.6798 - val_accuracy: 0.5803

Epoch 00007: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58025
Epoch 8/15
1011/1011 [==============================] - 8s 8ms/step - loss: 0.6797 - accuracy: 0.5830 - val_loss: 0.6798 - val_accuracy: 0.5803

Epoch 00008: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.58025
```

I tried to change  every single thing i saw here and there and nothing worked, I am sure I have no nan values in my data as i did remove them in the pre-processing steps. *I tried to run CNN to check if it is related to LSTM or not and got the same thing (neither one of the 2 things are changing)*. Also, after trying different optimizers, nothing has changed. Any help is really appreciated.

Here is a link of the dataset after doing all the pre-processing:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1punYl-f3dFbw1YWtw3M7hVwy5knhqU9Q/view?usp=sharing

Using Decision Tree I was able to get 85%

```
decesion_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(x_train, y_train)
dt_predictions = decesion_tree.predict(x_test)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, dt_predictions) # 85
```

Note: the predictions test has same values for all testing set (x_test), that tell us why the val_accuracy is not changing.

Comment: Can you provide a small subset of the dataset which can reproduce the issue or a link to the dataset itself ?

Comment: Why do you think 58% is not good ?

Comment: @Andrey actually this 58% is not good cz the model is predicting 1s only if i use softmax and same predictions if i use sigmoid in the last layer

Comment: @NiteyaShah I just shared the dataset after doing all the preprocessing.

Comment: In your setup, you set your learning rate to `0.0001`. That is really really small, hence your model is barely learning anything during the training. Can you increase you learning rate to `0.1` and report back if things changed or not? It is the line `opt = Adam(lr=0.0001,...` where you have to exchange the `lr = 0.0001` with `lr = 0.1`.

Comment: I am producing the same results. And I am also stuck, tbh. As an improvement to your approach, I normalized the columns before feeding to the NN. Also, I added more layers just to overfit the model on purpose. Or even, tried with a very small NN such that 10 neurons and the last layer only. But nope, the accuracy just gets stuck at 0.58. I feel it is a problem of the data, but I am very curious about what the actual problem is.

Comment: @Prefect this is the only thing i am thinking of, but i cant understand how Decision Tree can get me 85% while DL cant learn anything.

Comment: @YannikSuhre I already tried that tbh, it is only about how fast you get 58%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple issues here so I will try to address them all step by step.

1. The first is that machine learning data needs to have a pattern which the model can infer and predict.
   Stock prediction is highly irregular, nearly random and I would attribute any accuracy deviation from 50% to statistical variance.
2. NN can be very hard to train and 'There is no free lunch'

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *

file = pd.read_csv('dummy_db.csv')

x_train = np.expand_dims(file[['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3']].to_numpy(), axis=2)
y_train = file['Label'].to_numpy(np.bool)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape = (x_train.shape[1], 1), name="one"))) #. input_shape = (None, *x_train.shape) ,
model.add(Dropout(0.20))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=False, name="three")))
model.add(Dropout(0.10))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.10))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = SGD(learning_rate = 0, momentum = 0.1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=128, validation_split=0.1)
```

A zero LR train step to identify initial accuracy. You will see that the intial accuracy is 41%(This accuracy is a hit or miss as will explain later).

> 316/316 [==============================] - 10s 11ms/step - loss:
> 0.7006 - accuracy: 0.4321 - val_loss: 0.6997 - val_accuracy: 0.41

I am keeping the LR small `(1e-4)` so you can see the shift in accuracy happening

```py
opt = SGD(learning_rate = 1e-4, momentum = 0.1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15,batch_size=128, validation_split=0.1)
```

> Epoch 1/15 316/316 [==============================] - 7s 9ms/step -
> loss: 0.6982 - accuracy: 0.4573 - val_loss: 0.6969 - val_accuracy: 0.41

> Epoch 2/15 316/316 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step -
> loss: 0.6964 - accuracy: 0.4784 - val_loss: 0.6954 - val_accuracy: 0.41

> Epoch 3/15 316/316 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step -
> loss: 0.6953 - accuracy: 0.4841 - val_loss: 0.6941 - val_accuracy: 0.49

> Epoch 4/15 316/316 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step -
> loss: 0.6940 - accuracy: 0.4993 - val_loss: 0.6929 - val_accuracy: 0.51

> Epoch 5/15 316/316 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step -
> loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.5089 - val_loss: 0.6917 - val_accuracy: 0.54

> Epoch 6/15 316/316 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step -
> loss: 0.6918 - accuracy: 0.5209 - val_loss: 0.6907 - val_accuracy: 0.56

> Epoch 7/15 316/316 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step -
> loss: 0.6907 - accuracy: 0.5337 - val_loss: 0.6897 - val_accuracy: 0.58

> Epoch 8/15 316/316 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step -
> loss: 0.6905 - accuracy: 0.5347 - val_loss: 0.6886 - val_accuracy: 0.58

> Epoch 9/15 316/316 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step -
> loss: 0.6885 - accuracy: 0.5518 - val_loss: 0.6853 - val_accuracy: 0.58

** Rest of the runs left out for brevity **

If you rerun the training, you may see that model initially has a accuracy of 58 % and it never improves. This is because it has no features to actually to learn other than the minima that is seemingly present at 58% and one I wouldnt trust for actual cases.

Let me add some more proof for this

```py
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('dummy_db.csv')
sum(file['Label'])/len(file)
```

```
0.4176496772757623
```

Thats how many Trues there are, there are concurently 58% falses. So what is happening is that your model is learning to predict false for all cases and getting the sub-optimal 58% accuracy. We can prove this statement

```
sum(model.predict(x_train) < 0.5)
```

> array([44930])

That is the true reason for your recurring 58%, and I dont think it will ever do better.

3. You seem to not be using LSTMs properly. LSTMs inputs are of the format [batch, timesteps, feature] and I dont think your inputs are actually timesteps.
   you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549011/lstm-keras-input-shape-confusion), a question that explains quite well why LSTM is a bad choice for your data. There are better ML classifiers, both DL and non DL which are better at this than using LSTMs.
   Edit:
   https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38328/when-does-decision-tree-perform-better-than-the-neural-network explains this even better.

So what to do now?

1. Get better data.
2. Read literature where someone did stock prediction and see what exactly they did.

Comment: really interesting answer, before i accept your answer, how would you explain getting 85% accuracy using `Decision Tree` if there is no pattern to be recognized ? as you have the data already, you can check that too

Comment: Im not saying that that there may not be patterns in this dataset, but rather that it work beyond that. If you are simply learning the ropes of ML then there is nothing wrong with doing this. My issue will become relevant when you actually try to deploy this. While I dont know what your features actually mean, because stocks are so correlated with many factors, 3 parameters can hardly predict the outcome,

Comment: As for how decision trees can get 85%, can you tell on what segment you get that accuracy ?

Comment: what do you mean by what segment ? if you mean how to produce the same training and testing set, then setting random_state to 98 should do that `train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=98 )`. was that your question ?

Comment: I meant was it on train, test or validate?

Comment: oh, on testing set ofcourse, just updated the question, please see the code

Comment: tbh, the 3 selected features were chosen based on the `feature_importances_` of the decision tree model. this is how i reduced the number of features from 32 to 3 only. basically, that feature let you see the correlations between features when the model predicts a new input

Comment: If you read https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38328/when-does-decision-tree-perform-better-than-the-neural-network even there it is said that DTs outperform NN for structured data, which is where we are. I will happily retract my statement that this data has not enough information to learn. But my core inference is still correct I think, that the model cannot learn anything and is stuck at 0.58 because it just starts to predict everything as false.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you using Bidirectional on LSTM while trying to do a classification over stock-market ?
2. You should try Scaling your data: values of features_3 are way out of bounds.
3. I'm not sure feature selection is a good idea here! Your DT may perform better while selecting features.
   But I don't think reducing dimensionnality is a great idea when trying to find a manifold that splits a potentially very very high dimensionality space into your 2 labels.