# Implementing LSTM in Keras. ValueError: layer sequential is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to Keras and am attempting to implement an RNN.

My dataset as a whole consists of 431 records and 818 attributes. Each record is a 1D array of 818 values (each "value" being associated with an attribute for *that* record). Lastly, there is a 70-30 split to build the training and test sets, respectively.

I am encountering an error that says the following:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_62 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 817]
```

I have unfortunately spent an unnecessary number of hours attempting to resolve this issue, and am hoping that some of the veteran users of this library can be of help. I believe I had a version of this error earlier, but was able to resolve it with the discussion on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119320/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-lstm-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expected-ndim). I am not sure if the current error is *still* related to that discussion — I don't think it is. Note that viewing this discussion is not necessary to answering the question.

Below is a minimally reproducible example. All of the implementation is absolutely the same, except for that I have hard-coded in a smaller dataset. It is 6 1D arrays, each with six values. The exact same error occurs.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Masking, Embedding

data = [[3.0616e-03, 3.2530e-03, 2.6789e-03, 0.0000e+00, 1.9135e-04, 1.0000e+00],
 [1.1148e-02, 1.4231e-03, 1.8975e-03, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 1.0000e+00],
 [5.7723e-03, 7.5637e-03, 2.1895e-03, 0.0000e+00, 3.9809e-04, 1.0000e+00],
 [7.4699e-03, 1.2048e-03, 1.4458e-03, 0.0000e+00, 4.8193e-04, 1.0000e+00],
 [6.0682e-03, 4.1850e-04, 1.6740e-03, 0.0000e+00, 4.1850e-04, 1.0000e+00],
 [9.1189e-03, 7.6906e-04, 1.2085e-03, 0.0000e+00, 1.0987e-04, 1.0000e+00]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Separating out the features for training set. 
trainingInputs = df.iloc[0:(round(0.7 * df.shape[0])), :(df.shape[1] - 1)].values

#Separating out the target for training set.
trainingOutputs = df.iloc[0:(round(0.7 * df.shape[0])), (df.shape[1] - 1)].values

#Separating out the features for testing set.
testingInputs = df.iloc[(math.ceil(0.7 * df.shape[0])):, :(df.shape[1] - 1)].values

#Separating out the target for testing set. 
desiredOutputs = df.iloc[(math.ceil(0.7 * df.shape[0])):, (df.shape[1] - 1)].values

trainingInputs = trainingInputs.reshape(trainingInputs.shape[0], 1, trainingInputs.shape[1])

#trainingInputs = np.expand_dims(trainingInputs, 1)

model = Sequential()

# Going to another recurrent layer: return the sequence.
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape = (trainingInputs.shape[1:]), activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 1e-3, decay = 1e-5)

#Mean squared error.
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer = opt,
             metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainingInputs, trainingOutputs, epochs = 3, validation_data = (testingInputs, desiredOutputs))
```

Please let me know if any clarification is needed regarding the question. I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you've done is correct except you've forgotten to reshape your testing inputs :

```
testingInputs = testingInputs.reshape(testingInputs.shape[0], 1, testingInputs.shape[1])
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! I didn't realize this was needed. Thank you for the help!