# Preparing Pandas DataFrame for LSTM

Tags: python, pandas, keras, lstm

I'm trying to fit a LSTM classifier using Keras but don't understand how to prepare the data for training.

I currently have two dataframes for the training data. X_train contains 48 hand-crafted temporal features from IMU data, and y_train contains corresponding labels (4 kinds) representing terrain. The shape of these dataframes is given below:

```
X_train = X_train.values.reshape(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],1)
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
**(268320, 48, 1) (268320,)**
```

Model using `batch_size = (32,5,48)`:

```
def def_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=144,batch_size=(32, 5, 48),return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
    model.add(Dense(144, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))         
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))          
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])        
    return model

model_LSTM = def_model()

LSTM_history = model_LSTM.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=15, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), verbose=1)
```

The error that I am getting:
`ValueError: Shapes (32, 1) and (32, 48, 4) are incompatible`

Any insight into how to fix this particular error and any intuition into what Keras is expecting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62570576/10375049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the 5 in your batch size ? The `batch_size` argument in the LSTM layer indicates that your data should be in the form `(batch_size, time_steps, feature_per_time_step)`. If I am understanding correctly, your `data has time_steps = 1` and `feature_per_time_step = 48`.

Here is a sample of working code and the shape of each of them.

```
def def_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=144,batch_size=(32, 1, 48),return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
    model.add(Dense(144, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))         
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))          
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])        
    return model

model_LSTM = def_model()

X_train = np.random.random((10000,1,48))
y_train = np.random.random((10000,4))
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,1,4)

data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).batch(32)
model_LSTM.fit(data, epochs=15, verbose=1)
```

Passing `data` instead of `x_train` and `y_train` in your fit function will fit the model properly.

If you want to have 5 timesteps in your data, you will have to create your X_train in such a way to have it have a shape `(n_samples,5,48)`.

Comment: Can you explain why you reshaped y_train like that? y_train is meant to be a function of the 48 features.  X_train contains 268320 rows, each with 48 feature columns and a corresponding label in y_train.

Comment: Since you are using `model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax')) `, your model is expecting a response variable of shape `(nb_samples,4)` , with each example looking like so: `[0,0,1,0]`, with the 3rd class being the target class. If your output is encoded as the class number ([2] in the previous example), you would change the number of output units to 1 and changing the loss function to `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`